# Value Error and problem with shape during creation of Data Frame in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to combine coefficient from Liear Regression model with values from test dataset, nevertheless I have error like below, my code is below, do you know where is the problem and what can I do ?

[image]

[image]

I need something like below, where indexes are from X.columns and numbers are from LR.coef_.

[image]

Comment: No it is not good result by using your code, it is neccessairy to repare my code above, do you have any idea ?

Comment: Are you looking to add the coef as row to the data (X)? Then pd.concat([X, LR.coef_]) without axis argument will work

Comment: I edited my question by adding result which I need, do you maybe know how to achieve that ?

Comment: Have you tried reshaping LR.coef_ numpy array when passing it into the dataframe? That error is telling you that you passed in an array that is 1 row x 689 columns, but structure of the data frame you are trying to make is 689 rows x 1 column, so you need to reshape the array to be 689 rows x 1 column to populate your data frame. To do this you can create the dataframe as follows: `coefficientDataFrame1 = pd.DataFrame(LR.coef_.reshape(-1,1), X.columns, columns=["Coefficient"])`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the following example, `values` is a dataframe which has the same shape of your `LR.coef_`. To use its first row as column values in another dataframe, you can create a dict and pass that dict to [pandas.DataFrame()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html).

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

values = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((1, 689)))

X = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((2096, 689)))

frame = { 'coefficient': values.iloc[0] }

coefficient = pd.DataFrame(frame, index=X.columns)
```